# WPF many resources files for localization

Tags: wpf, resources, localization

Usually resources are stored in Resources.resx and Resources.[culture].resx files for localization. Is it possible to create other resources files with other names? For example, People.resx, Cars.resx, Whatever.resx..? If it's not possible how to separate Resources file into many parts?
I tried to create such file but Visual Studio doesn't want to handle it. When I type '.' after Appname.Properties it shows only two options - Resources and Settings, doesn't see my resource file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it - we can't use resource files for different cultures if we didn't create standard resource file. For example we might have created Cars.ro.resx, Cars.ru.resx but in order to use them we have to create Cars.resx. Moreover, it shouldn't be empty, we should double all valued from files for different cultures to that file. If we don't do that we can't reach those values from code.